# Next.js and i18next - two variables in single translation - instead of Link I get [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I have a Footer component:

```js
export default function Footer() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("layout-footer");
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  return (
    <footer className='py-6 mt-20 border-t-[1px] border-opacity-50'>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>{t("addresses")}</p>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>
        <Trans
          i18nKey='information'
          t={t}
          components={{
            currentYear,
            link: (
              <Link
                href='https://www.signinsolutions.com'
                className='text-green-600'
                rel='noreferrer'
                target='_blank'
              >
                Sign In Solutions
              </Link>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

json file:

```json
{
  "information": "© {{currentYear}} Sign In App Ltd is part of the {{link}} suite of brands providing global, cloud-based solutions to manage visitors, employees, workplaces and beyond."
}
```

I tried multiple different things without success - I just can't get seem to get that currentYear and Link component rendered in my translation at the same time - Link will always be as `[Object object]`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uA8S.png)

Comment: Have you tried `link: () => <Link />`

Comment: Yeah, it prints:


© 2023 Sign In App Ltd is part of the ()=>/*#__PURE__*/ (0,react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)((next_link__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default()), { href: "https://www.signinsolutions.com", className: "text-green-600", rel: "noreferrer", target: "_blank", children: "Sign In Solutions" }, void 0, false, void 0, void 0) suite of brands providing global, cloud-based solutions to manage visitors, employees, workplaces and beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [i18next interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) in this example. let me provide the draft of solution for you:

footer component should look like that:

```
export default function Footer() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("layout-footer");
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const link = "LINK HERE";

  return (
    <footer className='py-6 mt-20 border-t-[1px] border-opacity-50'>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>{t("addresses")}</p>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>
        {t("information", {currentYear, link} )}
      </p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

if you want to disable escaping then in your translation JSON file please use little minus character after opening double curly brackets `{{- variable_name}}` like that:

```
{
  "information": "© {{currentYear}} Sign In App Ltd is part of the {{- link}} suite of brands providing global, cloud-based solutions to manage visitors, employees, workplaces and beyond."
}
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION TO USE COMPONENT WITH TRANSLATION**

In the case when you want to use the whole component the best option is to use `Trans` component from `next-i18next`. The below example is showing how to do that:

```
export default function Footer() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("layout-footer");
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  return (
    <footer className='py-6 mt-20 border-t-[1px] border-opacity-50'>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>{t("addresses")}</p>
      <p className='text-sm text-center mb-6'>
        <Trans 
          i18nKey="information"
          t={t}
          components={[ <a href='https://www.signinsolutions.com' className='text-green-600' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank' /> ]}
          values={{currentYear}}
        />
      </p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

and then in JSON file:

```
{
  "information": "© {{currentYear}} Sign In App Ltd is part of the <0>Sign In Solutions</0> suite of brands providing global, cloud-based solutions to manage visitors, employees, workplaces and beyond."
}
```

Comment: Not working, the link needs to be next.js <Link> component, this method still gives me [object Object] instead of rendering <a> tag

Comment: @damycode - ok.. I understand what you want to achieve - please see once again my above answer - it has been extended with another example how to use component with translation..

Comment: I managed to solve it in a similar fashion as I realised I can get the year out and in the template rather than having it in the translation string (doesn't need to be translated) - it's pretty much the same what you've got. Using components prop in Trans to pass the <Link> component. 

Thanks for looking into this I'll mark yours as solution as I have solution that is very close to this.